# Range-based for loop, which one is faster?

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, char

If we use the range-based for loop with strings, is there any gain using

```
for (auto const & c : s)
```

over

```
for (auto c : s)

// c => char
// s => std::string
```

I'm asking this because chars which are just one byte in memory are not that expensive to copy, and this kept me curious last night.

I did some benchmarks on it!

**RESULT:**

```
// In Milliseconds

// 1000
// BY COPY: 7
// BY _REF: 5

// 10000
// BY COPY: 51
// BY _REF: 50

// 100000
// BY COPY: 503
// BY _REF: 501

// 1000000
// BY COPY: 5047
// BY _REF: 5101

// 10000000
// BY COPY: 52058
// BY _REF: 56160
```

**CODE:**

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

bool by_copy(std::string const & s);
bool by_const_ref(std::string const & s);

int main() {
    std::string const test {"0000000001"};

    auto start {std::chrono::steady_clock::now()};
    for (unsigned long long i {}; i < 10000000; ++i) {
        bool b {by_copy(test)};
        if (b) {}
    }
    auto end {std::chrono::steady_clock::now()};
    auto duration {std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count()};
    cout << "BY COPY: " << duration << '\n';

    start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (unsigned long long i {}; i < 10000000; ++i) {
        bool b {by_const_ref(test)};
        if (b) {}
    }
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
    cout << "BY _REF: " << duration << '\n';

    return 0;
}

bool by_copy(std::string const & s) {
    for (auto c : s) {
        if (c == '1') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool by_const_ref(std::string const & s) {
    for (auto const & c : s) {
        if (c == '1') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Out of curiosity, I also did benchmarks on by index, and it was way much more faster than the range-based for loops, why?

**RESULTS**

```
    // 1000
    // BY COPY: 7
    // BY _REF: 5
    // BYINDEX: 4

    // 10000
    // BY COPY: 59
    // BY _REF: 58
    // BYINDEX: 37

    // 100000
    // BY COPY: 526
    // BY _REF: 495
    // BYINDEX: 326

    // 1000000
    // BY COPY: 5751
    // BY _REF: 5038
    // BYINDEX: 3308

    // 10000000
    // BY COPY: 62202
    // BY _REF: 63002
    // BYINDEX: 38744
```

**the by_index function:**

```
bool by_index(std::string const & s) {
    for (size_t i {}; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        if (s[i] == '1') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: When you measured the difference, what did you find?

Comment: @KerrekSB Funny how questions with no measurement effort are sent to measure and questions with measurement effort are told their measurements are pointless and that only the disassembly matters :)

Comment: I haven't measured it yet.

Comment: @DagobertoPires measure first, then ask if the results are not what you expected.

Comment: Generated code for each: https://godbolt.org/g/b0VZeO - play "spot the difference" !

Comment: @Rotem that is because you should usually do both. First check disassembly to see if generated code is different. If not, measuring is pointless, otherwise it is essential. This question lacks both efforts of research.

Comment: @Rotem: That's probably over-simplifying. There are lots of different kinds of questions.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes of course, somewhat over-simplified and tongue in cheek.

Comment: @KerrekSB, I did the benchmarks, take a look at the updated question ;)

Comment: @DagobertoPires: Good. Try also with longer strings (several thousands or millions of characters long).

Comment: @KerrekSB, I'll try, but some of these take ages to finish.

Comment: @KerrekSB, I repeated the same tests, but this time I added a by index function, which happens to be the fastest in all occasions. Why? I was amazed by how fast it is when compared with the other two!

Comment: @DagobertoPires: did you compile with optimizations?

Comment: @PaulR: That's even funnier with `-O2`!

Comment: @KerrekSB: beautiful - I hadn't noticed that ! LOL !

Comment: On gcc I use O3, on Visual Studio I just used the default settings. I did it on Visual Studio ;) But why is it faster? xD Is it because there's no temporary variable in between?

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, I interpret your question such that you are iterating over the characters of a string - rather than iterating a container of strings.

No, there is no advantage. In fact, there is theoretically potential for the reference being slower due to the implied indirection. However, it is likely that both variations compile to exactly the same machine code because a decent optimizer will be able to avoid the indirections.

Comment: Isn't there a call to string constructor in the second case whereas there is not in the first?

Comment: @RawN if `s` is a string then `c` is a character.  No constructor there.

Comment: @RawN no, there are no strings constructed in either case.

Comment: I see, the auto gets evaluated to char so no call to string constructor needed, if I get this correctly.

Comment: @RawN Yes.  `c` has the type of the elements of `s`.  Not the type of `s`.  `std::string` elements are of type `char`.